# I need to get the values from checked checkbox and insert into Data Extension using AMPScript

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

```
<script runat=server language=javascript>
    function checkstatus() {
        for (count = 0; count < cntrl.value; count++) {
            if (form1.ordercheckbox[count].checked === true) {

                var accvalue = form1.ordercheckbox[count].value;
                alert(accvalue); // This gives me the exact value of checked box! How I can set this value into AMPScript variable? 

            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

After getting the values into Ampscript I need to add it to Data Extension using %%=InsertDE()=%%

Answer (score 1):

All the form field values can be retrieved using `RequestParameter("name")` function in the AMPScript. See the [RequestParameter](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#RequestParameter) link on the help pages.

One suggestion, since the checkbox controls handled slightly different by browsers ensure that you specify the `value` attribute on the `<input>` control in the form and then in AMPScript you can do a following check to distinguish whether or not it was selected:

```
IF (RequestParameter("checkbox-name") == "value") THEN
    /* case when it was selected*/
ELSE
    /* case when it was not selected */
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix server-side and client-side JavaScript.  SSJS is only executed on the server (much like PHP).  Client-side is like jQuery.

You can default checkboxes, with SSJS, but retrieving the values of those checkboxes will have to come from a form post.  [**Here's**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) a brief example.

The process would be when the `Request.Method == "GET"`, default the checkbox values.  The page loads, boxes are checked or unchecked and the user submit the form.  When `Request.Method == "POST"` then retrieve the current checkbox value from the form using `Request.GetFormField("VARNAME")` and insert the values into the data extension using [**InsertDE()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/insertde/) in AMPScript or [**Add()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/add/) in SSJS